# Mockito and private field / injected bean

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

What's the standard way of accessing/setting a private field in a Java-EE-Bean for Mockito testing? The test is as follows, but the MyDao-field is null, of course, if I run the (Mockito-) test. A NullPointerException is thrown for MyDao.

But I don't want to use Reflection - is there another way to do it or is the architecture of the service bad?

The class to test:

```
@Stateless
public class MyServiceImpl extends AbstractService {

@Inject
private MyDao myDao;

public MyEntity findByIdOrThrow( final long id ) throws Exception {
        if ( id > 0 ) {
            final MyEntity entity = myDao.findById( id );
            if ( entity == null ) {
                throw new Exception(  );
            } else {
                return entity;
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception(  );
        }
    }
```

The test class:

```
public class MyServiceImplTest {
private MyServiceImpl myServiceImpl;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    myServiceImpl = new ServiceServiceImpl();
}

@Test
public void findByIdOrThrow() throws Exception {
    Long id = 1L;
    when( myServiceImpl.findByIdOrThrow( id ) ).thenReturn( new MyEntity() );        
}}
```

Test class updated:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import de.myapp.dao.MyDao;
import de.myapp.entity.MyEntity;

@RunWith( MockitoJUnitRunner.class )
public class ServiceServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    public MyDao myDao;

    @InjectMocks
    public MyServiceImpl myServiceImpl;

    @Test
    public void findByIdOrThrow() throws Exception {
        final Long id = 1L;
        when( myServiceImpl.findByIdOrThrow( id ) ).thenReturn( new MyEntity() );
    }

}
```

Comment: Look into the `@InjectMocks` annotation - if you have an appropriate mock, it will set it to that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm supposing that `MyDao` is an interface. You have to do the following in your test class:

```
@Mock
private MyDao myDao;

@InjectMocks
private MyServiceImpl myServiceImpl;
```

and remove the `@BeforeEach` method. In this way you will inject a mock of your dao in te class. Using `Mockito.when` you will setup the dao-mock correctly to simulate your real dao. Do not forget to change the test declaration as it follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceImplTest
```

If you are using JUnit 5 the test class declaration should be the following:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
```

In this last case probably you can omit the `@RunWith`, but I am not sure.

Comment: If I do it like you suggested, I get a NullPointerException in the line with when( myServiceImpl. ...) because myServiceImpl is null. I added @RunWith( MockitoJUnitRunner.class) but it didn't help. Anyway, MyDao is an implementation, not an interface.

Comment: Can you post the updated class that gives you the NPE? Also consider that Mockito highly relies on interface and implementation separation to perform well.

Comment: Thank you very much: As you said, JUnit 5 was the problem. Adding
@ExtendWith( MockitoExtension.class )
did it (@RunWith wasn't necessary).